# How best to automate deployment for multiple environments

Tags: .net, deployment, automation, cicd

We have a large project that has several instances on the server.  Updating any instance takes a lot of time and effort. Each instance contains:

1. Web app dot net framework 4.6
2. Database
3. Dot net app that applies migrations
4. Couple Sync agents, hosted as a win services (dot net)
5. Moreover, each instance has individual settings (appsettings.json, nlog.config etc) which are long to edit manually.

Looks like we have to look at CI/CD. But I’m not a dev ops and have no idea which tools are better, modern. At the moment, deploying a test environment has become hell. How do you solve such problems?

Comment: There are a lot of tools for CI/CD. The best option would be to hire a experienced DevOps guy to handle this. Other things depend on you current infrastructure and amount of money you are willing to spend. You can look into Jenkis/TeamCity + Octopus (quite popular combination at least for older .NET).